# How to simplify code - Adding new input and button when clicking on certain button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add new input text and button when clicking on button.

But I think I did really HARD CODING...

I want to know if there is a way to simplify this hard coding.

Especially function `add_reference`.

```js
function add_reference() {
  var newGroupDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newGroupDiv.className = "form-group row mb-1 new-reference";

  var newColFirst = document.createElement('div');
  newColFirst.className = "col-sm-3";

  var newColSecond = document.createElement('div');
  newColSecond.className = "col-sm-9 input-group";

  var newInput = document.createElement('input');
  newInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  newInput.className = "form-control mr-2 reference-input";

  var newButtonDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newButtonDiv.className = "input-group-append";

  var newButton = document.createElement('button');
  newButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  newButton.className = "btn btn-block btn-ref btn-outline-info float-right";

  var newButtonIcon = document.createElement('i');
  newButtonIcon.className = "mdi mdi-plus-circle";

  newButton.appendChild(newButtonIcon);
  newButtonDiv.appendChild(newButton);
  newColSecond.appendChild(newInput);
  newColSecond.appendChild(newButtonDiv);
  newGroupDiv.appendChild(newColFirst);
  newGroupDiv.appendChild(newColSecond);

  return newGroupDiv;
};


newGroupDiv = add_reference();

$('.form-fieldset').append(newGroupDiv);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="form-fieldset">
  <div class="form-group row mb-1">
    <label class="col-sm-3 text-left control-label col-form-label" for="reference">REF</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 input-group">
      <input class="form-control mr-2 reference-input-first reference-input" id="reference" name="reference" required type="text" value="">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info btn-ref-first float-right"><i class="mdi mdi-plus-circle"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You code group the reusable code into a separate function.

Comment: BTW, if the code works and you want to refactor it into a better one, then try and post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead

Answer (score 0):

Use clone

```js
$('.form-fieldset').append($(".form-fieldset>div").clone(true));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="form-fieldset">
  <div class="form-group row mb-1">
    <label class="col-sm-3 text-left control-label col-form-label" for="reference">참조</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 input-group">
      <input class="form-control mr-2 reference-input-first reference-input" id="reference" name="reference" required type="text" value="">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info btn-ref-first float-right"><i class="mdi mdi-plus-circle"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```